# If first query result = second query result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use If statement for two query. If query one = query 2

```
string select = "Select ProfileId from Project_list Where ProjectId = @ProjectId";
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(select, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", querystring);
            object Project_listResult = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }


        string getProfileId = "SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = (@UserId)";
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(getProfileId, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
            object User_profileResult= myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }


        if (Project_listResult == User_profileResult)
        {
            addFollowerButton.Visible = true;

        }
```

This is the code I have so, but is not working.

Error   18  The name 'Project_listResult' does not exist in the current

Error   19  The name 'User_profileResult' does not exist in the current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define both values outside, so that are in scope to use them. Right now you are define both values in using, so those are just under the scope of only under and not available outside that, so you are getting that error.

A simple suggestion is that avoid use of keywords those are part of different language, as you are using select as variable name. This help to increase readability and increase confusion.

[Refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

```
object Project_listResult = null;
object User_profileResult = null;
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(select, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", querystring);
            Project_listResult = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }


        string getProfileId = "SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = (@UserId)";
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(getProfileId, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
            User_profileResult= myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }


        if (Project_listResult.Equals(User_profileResult))
        {
            addFollowerButton.Visible = true;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand you you're trying to compare the objects. So you've got to try

```
 if (Project_listResult.Equals(User_profileResult))
            addFollowerButton.Visible = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx